# Store initial value of variable in compute shader

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

I have a particle system written in a compute shader. My current code is the following

```c
#version 430 core

struct Particle{
    vec2 pos;
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer particleBuffer
{
    Particle particles[];
};


layout(local_size_x = 1024, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

uniform vec2[2048 * 2] initialPos;
uniform float t;

//[...]

void main()
{
    uint i = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    vec3 speed = go_up(vec3(particles[i].pos.xy, t));

    particles[i].pos += normalize(speed.xy) / 50.0;

    if (particles[i].pos.y > 1.0) 
        particles[i].pos = vec2(initialPos[i].x, initialPos[i].y);
}
```

I currently store the initial positions of each particle in the `initialPos` uniform using the following.

```cpp
particleComputeShader.use();
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++)
{
    particleComputeShader.set_vec2("initialPos["+ std::to_string(i) + "]", 
        particles[2 * i], particles[2 * i + 1]);
}
```

However, there is a limit on the number of uniforms which I can pass to a shader, limiting the amount of particles I can render on screen.

In a normal vertex shader I would usually use instancing, like so (code from learn opengl)

```c
#version 430 core

layout (location=0) in vec2 initialPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 aOffset;

void main()
{
    vec2 pos = initialPos * (gl_InstanceID / 100.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(pos + aOffset, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

How could I store the initial positions of my particles in the compute shader to restore it once they go offscreen? Should I use some form of instancing inside the compute shader? If so, how?

Comment: *"However, there is a limit on the number of uniforms "* - use a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object)

Comment: So I would write something like `layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer initBuffer {Particle initParticles[];}; ?`

Comment: I just did it and it worked, thanks!